# Json_decode returning truncated array

Tags: php, json

I'm json_encoding a multi-dimensional array, that dumps something like this:

```
$array = 

Array
(
    [a] = Array
        (
            [0] = Array
                (
                    [x0] = some-string
                    [y0] = some-string
                )
            [1] = Array
                (
                    [x1] = some-string
                    [y1] = some-string
                )
        )
    [b] = Array
        (
            [b1] = Array
                (
                    [0] = Array
                        (
                            ...
                        )
                )
            [b2] = Array
                (
                    [0] = Array
                        (
                            ...
                        )
                )
            ...
     )
)
```

But if I do the following and dump the results:

```
$json = json_encode( $array );
json_decode( $json, true );
```

Only array "a" is returned:

```
Array
(
    [a] = Array
        (
            [0] = Array
                (
                    [x0] = some-string
                    [y0] = some-string
                )
            [1] = Array
                (
                    [x1] = some-string
                    [y1] = some-string
                )
            ...
        )
    )
)
```

My first thought was an invalid character causing a parse error, but json_decode should only ever return null from a parse error, not a partially parsed array.

Additional info: The original array is nested up to 9 levels deep in places, and is a ~52,000 character string when encoded.

Update: I'm seeing this problem on PHP 5.2.11, so json_last_error() isn't available.  We have this code running on many different servers and this is the only case of this problem, so I'm guessing it is a server-based problem as opposed to code-based, for whatever that is worth.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: Try to check result of json_last_error().

Comment: @Alepac - My actual array dump would be over 1000 lines, so I'm just giving a representation.  The gist of the problem is that I have a multi-dimensional array, I json encode it, then I json decode it, and I only get back part of the array.

Comment: Did you see all the data in the string just encoded with the json_encode?

Comment: @OndřejMirtes - The issue is on a server running PHP 5.2.11 and json_last_error() is PHP >= 5.3.0.

Comment: @Alepac - Yes, all of the data encoded properly.  I can see it in the encoded string.  Is fails on the subsequent decode.

Comment: If you want to convert back to an array you should use `json_decode($json,true)` instead of `json_decode($json)`. If this can't help try to see the result of [json_last_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: @Alepac - Sorry that was a typo, as I actually was using json_decode( $json, true );  I updated my example code.  And see my comment above regarding json_last_error()...

Comment: did this ever get resolved?